# What checksumming technique will let me calculate the checksum of the whole from the checksums of its parts?

Tags: algorithm, hash, checksum, crc

I'd like to send several chunks of data over the network by simply concatenating them together, and I'd like to be able to use a checksum to verify that everything made it over ok (this is mainly intended as a defensive check against bugs, not because I've seen or expect actual low-level data corruption).  So I'm looking for a checksumming algorithm that will let me calculate the checksum of the whole from the checksums of the parts.

One simple example of a technique like that that I think would work is to just treat each byte of each chunk as an integer, and add all of those integers together (that, of course, wouldn't detect missing zero bytes).  Another would be to just calculate the lengths of each chunk (that, of course, wouldn't detect data changes that don't cause net insertions or deletions).  Another, I believe, would be to XOR all the bytes together, but this would only be able to generate 1-byte checksums (I could take the bytes 4 at a time, and XOR each of those units, but if chunk lengths aren't multiples of four, I'd have to get into messiness that I think would probably remove the ability to simply concatenate different chunks together).

So, I'm looking for a more serious checksumming or hashing algorithm that still would let me easily calculate the checksum for several concatenated chunks given the checksums of each chunk.  Do any exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incremental Checksums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173481/incremental-checksums)

Answer (score 0):

Correctly transferring messages over TCP requires a protocol.  This protocol must define the start, end or preferably both, of messages.  This means that you will always know the length of messages.  If your protocol puts the lenth at the start and integer checksum at the end of the messages, missing zero bytes will be detected because the transmitted checksum will then be recovered from the wrong bytes in the stream and so will be wrong, on average, 65535 times out of 65536.